# Frontend call --> Transaction does not go through, no error message displayed

Tags: truffle-contract, frontend

I'm trying to build a frontend for my Dapp and first, I wanted to test if I can initiate a transaction at all. 
I have a Button which calls the storeInput() function. Then, it should invoke the storeQueryResults(uint256 id1, uint256 id2, string text1, string text2) function of my smart contract. This is my index.js file:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0'

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      App.web3Provider = new 
      Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON("QueryResultHandler.json", function(queryResultHandler) {
      App.contracts.QueryResultHandler = TruffleContract(queryResultHandler);
      App.contracts.QueryResultHandler.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
      console.log(App.contracts);
      return App.render();
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        console.log(App.account);
      }
    });
  },

  storeInput: function() {
    App.contracts.QueryResultHandler.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.storeQueryResults(1, 2, "a", "b", {
        from: App.account
      });
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  }

};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

I'm using MetaMask, and I'm actually trying to follow Truffle's pet-shop tutorial regarding the config. http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

However, the button seems to do nothing, it doesn't even fire an error message and in Ganache, no new transactions are displayed. I really don't know, what I'm missing.